# Inserting ERB with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I’m trying to insert an ERB element into my page using JS, but the insertAdjacentHTML method doesn’t work and simply put my erb element as a string

I tried with `raw`, `.html_safe` and `append()`, but none of these work.

here's basically what I want to do

```
btn_plus.addEventListener('click', () => {
    btn_plus.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `<%= select_tag :rg1, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 'id', 'email') %>`);
  })
```

and as a result it simply puts `<%= select_tag :rg1, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 'id', 'email') %>` as a string on my page

What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: rails tags are converted to html on server side so It won't work in js file because it will run on client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in an `.html.erb` file, you can use an actionview helper to generate a string like this:

```html
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    const foo = '<%= select_tag(:foo, raw("<option>bar</option><option>baz</option>")) %>'
    $('#put_it_here').append(foo)
<% end %>
```

you can use `options_for_select` too, but I didn't have anything handy to check it, so my example just uses raw `options` tags.

the resulting output in the browser is:

```html
<script>
//<![CDATA[

  const foo = '<select name="foo" id="foo"><option>bish</option><option>bash</option></select>'
  $('#put_it_here').append(foo)

//]]>
</script>
```

and you can use the string 'foo' in your javascript expression to insert it dynamically where you wish, I've used jQuery here.

If you need to use the `<select>...</select>` html string in an included js file, you can declare it in the `.html.erb` file and later use it in the included file.

Answer (score 1):

Abdul's comment is correct. Let me explain you in detail on how Rails rendering and JS works.

When you enter the URL on address bar, say `http://url.com/articles/1`, Rails recieves this request and looks for `Articles#show` action, then converts the `show.html.erb` file to an `.html` file(+ replaces dynamic stuff in this file) and then sends this HTML file to the browser. All this stuff is happening on the server side. Your in browser JS has nothing to do with it till now.

Now when you're browser recieves the HTML(+ CSS and JS files), the browser will render the HTML file and it will now execute the JS in browser. So now your `btn_plus.addEventListener` function is executed. It will do nothing to the rails part, it will just update the DOM. That's why when you inspect in dev tools you'll see

```
<%= select_tag :rg1, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 'id', 'email') %>
```

rather than seeing an `<select></select>` tag.

You can do something like this. Include your `<%= select_tag :rg1, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 'id', 'email') %>` where ever you want it in your `.html.erb` file. Then in your JS, you could do something like this:

```
const rg1 = document.getElementById('rg1');
const btn_plus = document.getElementById('btn_plus'); // change your ID here if it's different

// Hide the select tag
rg1.style.display = 'none';

// On btn click, show the select tag:
btn_plus.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rg1.style.display = 'inline-block'; // or `block` or anything you want
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explications ! Actually I thought about the hidden/show method, but I want to add a new `select` every time the user clicks on a button

Comment: Ok, I think then you can do something similar to Les's Answer. Create a dynamic `javascript_tag` and append it everytime a user clicks the button.

Comment: yep, it worked. Thanks again for clarifying it for me !